# Python/Django PDF Creation Not Working For Me

Tags: django, python-3.x, pdf-generation

I'm just getting started on creating a pdf from a binary string. Here is my code:

```
...
resp = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename="mypdf.pdf"'
resp.write(b'Hello world.')
return resp
...
```

The problem is that I keep getting an error that says "Failed to load PDF document." What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please follow the official instructions. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-pdf/

Comment: Your code does *not create* a pdf. It writes a string to the response and *falsely claims* that that string is a pdf.